# how enable anonymous access in ElasticSearch 5.3

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I just have downloaded the ElasticSearch, LogStash and Kibana version 5.3 (until few hours ago I was using 5.2.something). I installed XPack in each of ELK. After that I can't use logstash anymore.

LogStash error:

./logstash -f /log_to_elastic53.conf

```
...
    [2017-04-06T19:25:55,704][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>#<URI::HTTP:0x3c6582db URL:http://127.0.0.1:9200/>, :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::BadResponseCodeError, :error=>"Got response code '401' contacting Elasticsearch at URL 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/'"}
```

my log_to_elastic53.conf

```
input { stdin { } }
output {
  elasticsearch { hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200"] }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

I setup ElasticSearch to accept anonymous call that way:

source idea: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/anonymous-access.html

elasticsearch.yml

```
xpack.security.authc:
  anonymous:
    username: anonymous_user 
    roles: role1, role2 
    authz_exception: false
```

P.S. I tried both false/true in authz_exception

Interesting that Kibana is complaining about some permission as well but I am wondering if it is related to Debian than ELK: Failed to extract the phantom.js archive

./kibana

```
undefined accessed the autoload lists which are no longer available via the Plugin API.Use the `ui/autoload/*` modules instead.
undefined accessed the autoload lists which are no longer available via the Plugin API.Use the `ui/autoload/*` modules instead.
  log   [22:24:55.244] [warning] Plugin "Sense" was disabled because it expected Kibana version "2.0.0-snapshot", and found "5.3.0".
  log   [22:24:55.499] [info][status][plugin:kibana@5.3.0] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [22:24:55.568] [info][status][plugin:elasticsearch@5.3.0] Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch
  log   [22:24:55.575] [info][status][plugin:xpack_main@5.3.0] Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch
  log   [22:24:55.739] [info][status][plugin:graph@5.3.0] Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch
  log   [22:24:55.747] [info][status][plugin:monitoring@5.3.0] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [22:24:55.751] [warning][reporting] Generating a random key for xpack.reporting.encryptionKey. To prevent pending reports from failing on restart, please set xpack.reporting.encryptionKey in kibana.yml
  log   [22:24:55.756] [info][status][plugin:reporting@5.3.0] Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch
  log   [22:24:55.958] [error][reporting] ExtractError: Failed to extract the phantom.js archive
    at Extract.<anonymous> (/home/demetrio/Servers/DBs/kibana-5.3.0-amd64/usr/share/kibana/plugins/x-pack/plugins/reporting/server/lib/extract/bunzip2.js:18:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at Extract.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Extract.destroy (/home/demetrio/Servers/DBs/kibana-5.3.0-amd64/usr/share/kibana/plugins/x-pack/node_modules/tar-stream/extract.js:191:17)
    at onunlock (/home/demetrio/Servers/DBs/kibana-5.3.0-amd64/usr/share/kibana/plugins/x-pack/node_modules/tar-stream/extract.js:69:26)
    at stat (/home/demetrio/Servers/DBs/kibana-5.3.0-amd64/usr/share/kibana/plugins/x-pack/node_modules/tar-fs/index.js:232:23)
    at /home/demetrio/Servers/DBs/kibana-5.3.0-amd64/usr/share/kibana/plugins/x-pack/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:46:53
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
  log   [22:24:55.959] [error][reporting] Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/lib/kibana/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64'
    at Error (native)
  log   [22:24:55.960] [error][status][plugin:reporting@5.3.0] Status changed from yellow to red - Insufficient permissions for extracting the phantom.js archive. Make sure the Kibana data directory (path.data) is owned by the same user that is running Kibana.
  log   [22:24:55.968] [info][status][plugin:security@5.3.0] Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch
  log   [22:24:55.969] [warning][security] Generating a random key for xpack.security.encryptionKey. To prevent sessions from being invalidated on restart, please set xpack.security.encryptionKey in kibana.yml
  log   [22:24:55.972] [warning][security] Session cookies will be transmitted over insecure connections. This is not recommended.
  log   [22:24:56.022] [info][status][plugin:searchprofiler@5.3.0] Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch
  log   [22:24:56.033] [info][status][plugin:tilemap@5.3.0] Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch
  log   [22:24:56.042] [info][status][plugin:console@5.3.0] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [22:24:56.217] [info][status][plugin:elasticsearch@5.3.0] Status changed from yellow to green - Kibana index ready
  log   [22:24:56.219] [info][status][plugin:timelion@5.3.0] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [22:24:56.223] [info][listening] Server running at http://localhost:5601
  log   [22:24:56.225] [info][status][ui settings] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [22:24:56.355] [info][license][xpack] Imported license information from Elasticsearch: mode: trial | status: active | expiry date: 2017-05-06T18:53:19-03:00
  log   [22:24:56.365] [info][status][plugin:monitoring@5.3.0] Status changed from green to yellow - Waiting for Monitoring Health Check
  log   [22:24:56.368] [info][status][plugin:xpack_main@5.3.0] Status changed from yellow to green - Ready
  log   [22:24:56.369] [info][status][plugin:graph@5.3.0] Status changed from yellow to green - Ready
  log   [22:24:56.370] [info][status][plugin:reporting@5.3.0] Status changed from red to green - Ready
  log   [22:24:56.371] [info][status][plugin:security@5.3.0] Status changed from yellow to green - Ready
  log   [22:24:56.371] [info][status][plugin:searchprofiler@5.3.0] Status changed from yellow to green - Ready
  log   [22:24:56.372] [info][status][plugin:tilemap@5.3.0] Status changed from yellow to green - Ready
  log   [22:24:58.357] [info][status][plugin:monitoring@5.3.0] Status changed from yellow to green - Ready
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of allowing anonymous access which has high security risk, you could follow [the official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/5.3/logstash.html#ls-http-auth-basic) to configure a role and user for Logstash to connect Elasticsearch.

> Logstash needs to be able to manage index templates, create indices, and write and delete documents in the indices it creates.
>
> To set up authentication credentials for Logstash:
>
> 1. Create a logstash_writer role that has the manage_index_templates cluster privilege, and the write, delete, and create_index privileges for the Logstash indices. You can create roles from the Management > Roles UI in Kibana or through the role API:
>
>    ```
>    POST _xpack/security/role/logstash_writer
>    {
>      "cluster": ["manage_index_templates", "monitor"],
>      "indices": [
>        {
>          "names": [ "logstash-*" ], 
>          "privileges": ["write","delete","create_index"]
>        }
>      ]
>    }
>    ```
> 2. Create a logstash_internal user and assign it the logstash_writer role. You can create users from the Management > Users UI in Kibana or through the user API:
>
>    ```
>    POST _xpack/security/user/logstash_internal
>    {
>      "password" : "changeme",
>      "roles" : [ "logstash_writer"],
>      "full_name" : "Internal Logstash User"
>    }
>    ```
> 3. Configure Logstash to authenticate as the logstash_internal user you just created. You configure credentials separately for each of the Elasticsearch plugins in your Logstash .conf file. For example:
>
>    ```
>    input {
>        ...
>        user => logstash_internal
>        password => changeme
>      }
>    filter {
>        ...
>        user => logstash_internal
>        password => changeme
>      }
>    output {
>      elasticsearch {
>        ...
>        user => logstash_internal
>        password => changeme
>      }
>    ```